# How do I find the nearest point to a supplied point that is not overlapped by an array of circles

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to create a system where you "paint" an area with your character using ever-increasing sized circles that you place down whenever you exit your already painted area and I'm trying to give the player an arrow that points them towards the nearest non-painted area. (bonus points if you can find if the point is within a given rectangle bounds, "completing" it if it cannot be)

The array consists of circles defined by their center position and radius, so this is not grid based, purely coordinates.

I have no idea where to start because my experience in trigonometry/geometry/whatever maths field is required in this is very limited, so I've been mostly trying ChatGPT, which has given pretty unsatisfactory results for this pretty specific issue, and I think I broke it many times trying.

Answer (score 1):

Solved in Lua, I compared every circle with each other and found each intersection point that was not contained within another circle and inserted them into a "candidates" array, then did something similar with all the nearest edges to every circle overlapping the cursor, and found the closest point in the array of candidates.

Independent function: (Roblox Lua)

[Demonstration GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0HQR.gif)

```
function findNearestEmptySpot(point,circles)

    -- point is a Vector2 or any array containing 2D coordinates indexed as "X" and "Y"
    -- circles is an array of arrays formatted as such: {pos=Vector2,radius=number}
    -- if the point is not inside any circles, returns the points position
    
    local spotCandidates = {}
    
    local function distance(pos1,pos2)
        return math.sqrt((pos2.X-pos1.X)^2 + (pos2.Y-pos1.Y)^2)
    end
    
    local function getCirclesOverlappingWithPoint(pos)
        local overlappingCircles = {}
        for _,circle in pairs(circles) do
            if distance(pos,circle.pos) < circle.radius-.001 then
                table.insert(overlappingCircles,circle)
            end
        end
        return overlappingCircles
    end
    
    local function getNearestEdgeOfCircleFromPoint(pos,circlePos,r)
        
        local x1,y1,x2,y2 = circlePos.X,circlePos.Y,pos.X,pos.Y
        local d = distance(pos,circlePos)
        
        if d < r then
            local x3 = x1 + r * (x2 - x1) / d
            local y3 = y1 + r * (y2 - y1) / d
            return Vector2.new(x3,y3)
        else
            return pos
        end
        
    end
    
    --get nearest edges
    local overlappedCircles = getCirclesOverlappingWithPoint(point)
    if #overlappedCircles > 0 then
        for _,circle in pairs(overlappedCircles) do
            local edge = getNearestEdgeOfCircleFromPoint(point,circle.pos,circle.radius)
            if #getCirclesOverlappingWithPoint(edge) == 0 then
                table.insert(spotCandidates,edge)
            end
        end
    else
        return point
    end
    ---
    
    --get all intersections
    for i1 = 1, #circles-1 do
        local c1 = circles[i1]
        for i2 = i1+1, #circles do
            local c2 = circles[i2]
            
            local p1,p2 = c1.pos,c2.pos
            local d = distance(p1,p2)
            local r1,r2 = c1.radius,c2.radius
                
            if d > r1 + r2 then
                -- the circles do not intersect
            elseif d < math.abs(r1 - r2) then
                -- one circle is completely contained within the other
            else
                -- the circles intersect
                local a = (r1 * r1 - r2 * r2 + d * d) / (2 * d)
                local h = math.sqrt(r1 * r1 - a * a)
                
                local xm = p1.X + a * (p2.X - p1.X) / d
                local ym = p1.Y + a * (p2.Y - p1.Y) / d
                
                --calculate first intersection
                local xs1 = xm + h * (p2.Y - p1.Y) / d
                local ys1 = ym - h * (p2.X - p1.X) / d
                
                --calculate second intersection
                local xs2 = xm - h * (p2.Y - p1.Y) / d
                local ys2 = ym + h * (p2.X - p1.X) / d
                
                local intersectionA,intersectionB = Vector2.new(xs1,ys1),Vector2.new(xs2,ys2)
                
                if #getCirclesOverlappingWithPoint(intersectionA) == 0 then
                    table.insert(spotCandidates,intersectionA)
                end
                
                if #getCirclesOverlappingWithPoint(intersectionB) == 0 then
                    table.insert(spotCandidates,intersectionB)
                end
                
            end
            
        end
    end
    ---
    
    --find nearest empty spot
    local nearest,nearestDist = nil,math.huge
    for _,candidatePos in pairs(spotCandidates) do
        local d = distance(point,candidatePos)
        if d < nearestDist then
            nearest = candidatePos
            nearestDist = d
        end
    end
    
    return nearest
    
end
```